# Using Angular6 Mat-Table dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm developing an Angular app which requires I display data which I retrieve from an API. Since I don't know exactly what data I would retrieve, and also this is a model I need to use for different tables, I need to make it both generate columns dynamically, but also fill every cell too.

The JSON I retrieve and I need to print in the table is similar to this:

```
[
    {
        "attributes": [],
        "brandReference": "f805a08df4c236ddb431e14a38419690",
        "computedPOS": "BEXFY_HEADQUARTERS",
        "deviceType": 1,
        "friendlyName": "BEXFY_TRANSPARENT_LED",
        "id": "953e9414d7a51e8-e0-681def0b02b5",
        "isMonitored": true,
        "location": "entrance",
        "posReference": "78fcef0f12993d52b2d2906dc4ce48d8",
        "timetable": [],
        "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
    },
    {
        "attributes": [],
        "brandReference": "185fd549-4410-462b-a610-fe6b61c91cf6",
        "comments": "",
        "computedPOS": "BEXFY_HEADQUARTERS",
        "deviceType": 1,
        "friendlyName": "BEXFY_AUDIO_OFICINA",
        "id": "79eaa7f5f6603809-e0-681def0b0290",
        "location": "",
        "posReference": "78fcef0f12993d52b2d2906dc4ce48d8",
        "timetable": [],
        "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
    },
    {
        "attributes": [],
        "brandReference": "185fd549-4410-462b-a610-fe6b61c91cf6",
        "comments": "",
        "computedPOS": "BEXFY_HEADQUARTERS",
        "deviceType": 1,
        "friendlyName": ".BEXFY_AUDIO_ADRI",
        "id": "97bf675e3e237bcd-e0-681def0b029f",
        "location": "",
        "posReference": "78fcef0f12993d52b2d2906dc4ce48d8",
        "timetable": [],
        "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
    }
]
```

Please note that the object property keys could change, so I can't hardcode something like element.friendlyName. I receive which key names I should use through an array that looks like this.

```
["friendlyName", "computedPOS", "location"]
```

So in order to make it work, I made something like this.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource.data" class="mat-elevation-z8" style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of modelCols; let colIndex = index" matColumnDef={{nameCols[colIndex]}}>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{nameCols[colIndex]}}</th>
    {{log(modelCols)}}
    <div *ngFor="let column of modelCols;">
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{log(element[column])}}
        {{element[column]}}
      </td>
    </div>

  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="nameCols"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: nameCols;"></tr>
</table>
```

The problem with this, is that it results in a repeat of the first value ("friendlyName") over each column of the row. Something like this.

[image]

While the intended way of working is this:

[image]

Comment: Rather than adding images of your `console`, it would be helpful if you add the actual data to your question along with the relevant component code. Better yet, add an example on StackBlitz of what you have tried.

Comment: i added the code. can't exactly share what i have tried, but mostly is what i already shown on the op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be looping over `nameCols` to show your dynamic columns. Whatever columns your API asks you to show is all you need to iterate over to show your columns. Since you are using `element[column]` to display the item in the row. It will only display the needed item.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of nameCols; let colIndex = index" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[column]}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-dynamic-cols) with your data. This way even if a set of different columns comes from the API to display, all you need to do is update `nameCols` to display the right columns. The template will take care of the rest and show the associated data to the columns shown.